# Differences beteween switch- and if-statements

Tags: perl, if-statement, switch-statement

Do these two statements behave equally or could they yield different results?

```
if ( ... ) {...}
elsif( ... ) {... }
elsif( ... ) { ... }
else { ... }
```

.

```
given ( ... ) {
    when ( ... ) { ... }
    when ( ... ) { ... }
    default { ... }
}
```

I've found the problem - with a modified ninth "when" it works now.

```
...
no warnings qw(numeric);
my $c = &getch();

given ( $c ) {
when ( $c == $KEY_LEFT and 1 > 0 ) { say 1; say $c }
when ( $c == $KEY_RIGHT ) { say 2; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cH" or $c eq "\c?" ) { say 3; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cC" ) { say 4; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cX" or $c eq "\cD" ) { say 5; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cA" ) { say 6; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cE" ) { say 7; say $c } 
when ( $c eq "\cL" ) { say 8; say $c } 
when ( not( not $SpecialKey{$c} ) ) { say 9; say $c } 
when ( ord( $c ) >= 32 ) { say 10; say $c } 
default { say 11; say $c }
}

if ( $c == $KEY_LEFT and 1 > 0 ) { say 1; say $c }
elsif ( $c == $KEY_RIGHT ) { say 2; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cH" or $c eq "\c?" ) { say 3; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cC" ) { say 4; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cX" or $c eq "\cD" ) { say 5; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cA" ) { say 6; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cE" ) { say 7; say $c } 
elsif ( $c eq "\cL" ) { say 8; say $c } 
elsif ( $SpecialKey{$c} ) { say 9; say $c } 
elsif ( ord( $c ) >= 32 ) { say 10; say $c } 
else { say 11; say $c }

close TTYIN;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you can do with the `given/when`, you can do with `if/elsif/else`. The idea is that `when/given` is suppose to be easier to read, and can automatically use *smartmatching* by default while you have to specify smart matching with the `if/else` statement.

I didn't parse through your code to make sure they're exact equivalents, but it looks like you've got more or less the right idea about `if/elsif/else` and `given/when`.

I never really understood the desire for what was referred to as the *switch statement*. It was something Perl coders always complained about -- the lack of a *switch statement* in Perl. Maybe it's a C thing that most Perl developers fondly remember. But I never found the `if/elsif/else` statements that bad.

What really confuses me is that when they finally implemented the *switch statement*, they didn't call it `switch`. Why the heck not?

And why `say` instead of `printnl`?

And, why `last` and `next` instead of `break` and `continue`. Why not simply use the standard names that other languages already use?

But enough of this Seinfeld style whining...

As [davorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/davorg) said, there's a big difference between a hash key that doesn't exist, a hash key that exists, but isn't defined, and a hash key that's defined, but gets evaluated to false:

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw(uninitialized);

my %hash;
$hash{FOO} = "bar";

if (not exists($hash{BAR})) {
print "\$hash{FOO} doesn't exist\n";
}
if (not defined($hash{BAR})) {
print "\$hash{BAR} is undefined\n";
}
if (not $hash{BAR}) {
print "\$hash{BAR} evaluates to false\n";
}
if ($hash{BAR} eq undef) {
print "\$hash{BAR} is equal to 'undef'\n";
}
```

You can see that `$hash{BAR}` doesn't even exist as a key in the `%hash` hash, but it is also undefined, and it evaluates as `false`. And, you can also see that it also evaluates as `undef` (notice I had to set `no warnings qw(uninitialized);` to prevent it from complaining about `$hash{BAR}` being uninitialized in my last `if` statement).

However, if I do this:

```
$hash{FOO} = bar;
$hash{BAR} = undef;
```

The first `if` statement no longer evaluates as `true` because the key `BAR` now does exist in the hash, but the value is still undefined and still evaluates as `false`.

And, if I did this:

```
$hash{FOO} = bar;
$hash{BAR} = 0;
```

`$hash{BAR}` now exists as a key in `%hash`, and it is no longer `undefined`, but it still evaluates as `false`.

I like simply being able to say this:

```
if (not $hash{BAR}) {
```

because it is short and sweet, and probably does what I want. However, I do have to understand the difference between existence of a key in a hash, evaluation to `false`, and not being `defined` as three separate things. It can be important if you have a subroutine that could return a `NULL` string or zero value:

```
if (not foo($bar)) {
    die qq(Error of some sort\n);
}

sub foo {
    $bar = <FOO> or return;
    return chomp($bar);
}
```

If there's a blank line in my file, it'll return a `NULL` string, but the subroutine will still return a defined value. The above probably does not do what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Your supposedly "fixed" version now does different things in the two versions of the code. Checking if a key exists in a hash is completely different to checking whether the associated value is true.

There are three different truth values you can get from a hash - whether the key exists in the hash, whether the associated value is defined and whether the associated value is true or false. This code should demonstrate the difference between the three:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
  key1 => undef,
  key2 => 0,
  key3 => 1,
);

foreach (qw(key1 key2 key3 key4)) {
  check_key($_);
}

sub check_key {
  my $k = shift;

  print "Key $k ";
  if (exists $hash{$k}) {
    print 'exists. ';
  } else {
    print "doesn't exist. ";
  }

  print 'Value ';

  if (defined $hash{$k}) {
    print 'is defined ';
  } else {
    print 'is not defined ';
  }

  print 'and is ';

  if ($hash{$k}) {
    print "true\n";
  } else {
    print "false\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose they are now equivalent.

Comment: If so, could I write this more directly?

Comment: See my other answer for a better explanation of why your original code didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer as I've just realised what the real problem is.

Your "when ($SpecialKey{$c})" is equivalent to "if ($_ ~~ $SpecialKey{$c})". And as "given" has set $_ to $c that's the same as "if ($c ~~ $SpecialKey{$c})". When comparing two scalar values (and I assume that's what we've got here) the smart match operator looks for values that are numbers and uses "eq" or "==" as appropriate.

So your code is effectively equivalent to "if ($c == $SpecialKey{$c})". And that's completely different to "if ($SpecialKey{$c})".

Comment: In the ninth case ($SpecialKey{$c}) I need only to know, if it is true. I've changed it to "when ( not( not $SpecialKey{$c} ){...}" but it doesn't look nice with the two negations.

Answer (score 0):

They behave totally equal.

Comment: except `given` is available only in newer versions of perl.

Comment: Actually, they don't work exactly the same. "when ($scalar)" is the same as "if ($_ eq $scalar)" and that's what is causing the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

given / when has implicit smart matching:

> Most of the power comes from implicit smart matching:
>
> > 1. when($foo)
>
> is exactly equivalent to
>
> > 1. when($_ ~~ $foo)

I don't think if/else does that(?)

See [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

EDIT:
Guess this doesn't really matter when using given/when the way OP is, but it still answers the question :)

Comment: Actually, it _does_ answer the question. It explains exactly why one of the conditions was acting differently in the "when" case.